# Searching Private Videos with the Advanced Vimeo API

Tags: api, video, vimeo

Using the Advanced Vimeo API, how can I search through all of an authenticated user's private videos? I am particularly interested in the user's private videos that have an `embed_privacy` of `anywhere`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vimeo's search does not expose any private videos on site, or through the API.

The best way to implement this would be to call vimeo.videos.getall (see the [playground](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getAll/playground)) and search through the data on your end.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.